# How to merge Objective C and Swift in Xcode9?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode9

I already merged my methods in objective C code. In Xcode 8.3 I can see ModuleName-Swift.h file in **Objective-C Generated Interface Header Name** .I import this file in .m file but with the Xcode 9, when I import the file, I across the problem: "Cant find ModuleName-Swift.h file". How can I fix this?

Comment: I had this problem when my Bridging header file the path is wrongly given in the build settings. Please check yours on that side.

Comment: Thank you! That was the problem.